# How to detect resource variable typos in Android Studio (ex: "%1$ s")

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources, android-lint

Android crashes are often caused by a resource containing `%1$ s` when `%1$s` was intended.
To my surprise, Android Studio does not show these syntax errors:

[image]

↑ The real syntax error above is the `%1$ s` (makes the app crash), not the ellipsis that Android Studio highlights.

How to check for resource variable typos in Android Studio?
I am looking for the equivalent of `lint --check StringFormatInvalid`.

*Context: Many semi-automatic language translation tools break variables, making apps crash.*

## What I have tried, does not work:

[image: Android Studio Lint Invalid format string]
[image: Highlighting level Inspections]

Comment: I am aware that my suggestion is slightly off topic, but nonethless: Why don't you write (unit) tests therefore? I am not fluent with the Android SDK but I would be surprised if there wasn't a way to read all `resource`s and have them evaluated (and fail when wrong).

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann: If such a tool existed it would be on-topic. The syntax of variables is not trivial though, not something that can be casually implemented in each app's unit tests.

Comment: I didn't mean to implement a syntax checker but rather use the Android API to execute what causes the _crash_ at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

in Intellij it is possible to create custom inspections. I am not sure if it is possible in Android Studio.

Follow the link:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-custom-inspections.html

edit:

after follow the steps in the link you see in the next image my created inspection:
[image]

In the next image you see the basic configuration of the inspection:
[image]

In the next two images you see the setting of the variables.
Only the used regex is not the ready. You must write it for general variable using (between $ and . is a space):
[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried Inspections but it does not highlight variable syntax errors, I updated my question to show that better.

Comment: This could be a first start. Unfortunately, checking variables is rather complex so we will need a lot of regexps... I actually tried a few years ago and could only get something half-satisfying with 10 combined regexps.

Comment: When regexps to hard, it is also possible to write a Script in Groovy (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html#script_constraints)

Answer (score 2):

Every thing in `strings.xml` between `<string>` and `</string>` is merely a string for Android studio and lint. It will not identify syntax typos. Syntax errors/typos means error with code and not strings. You'll need to make sure that these are written right by yourself or create your own script to do these checks on the `string.xml` file. There is no inbuilt mechanism to identify code in strings and then check for syntax errors in them.

The highlighted thing with ellipses is there because it is a grammatical (optimization) error. **If you make a spelling/grammatical mistake in `strings.xml` it will be highlighted.** Example below:

[image]

**But, if you intend to put in formats/code as strings it needs to be handled on your own or using some custom script that you'll need to write by yourself**. Or as mentioned by **@Rüdiger** in his comment on the question, you can write unit test cases to check the sanity and integrity of your strings in `strings.xml`.

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing available except grammar check and source code? Eclipse was very good at checking the syntax of variables embedded in resource strings.

Comment: See this for all checks that lint does: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks ... I could relate only translations and spellings with during resources. See if you find anything else relevant in the list.

Comment: That link contains only 1 relevant paragraph (StringFormatInvalid), which is already shown by the screenshot in my question.

Comment: Yes, I thinks these are all the checks they got in android studio as of today. May be in future we can hope to see other checks that eclipse send to be doing and are still missing in android studio.